# SQL Server 2008. I want to be able to edit multi line character data like I used to be able to in Enterprise Mgr

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I want to be able to insert and update rows with embedded carriage returns even if the column if of type text or ntext.

Since there seems to be no GUI way to do this, does anyone know of a free tool that does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Starting with SQL Server 2005, the ability to enter a line-break using the Results pane in Management Studio was removed (you can do it in SQL Server 2000's Enterprise Manager). That means either scripting the query to include a line break or using another tool like Toad, [DBVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/), [SQL LOB Editor](http://www.withdata.com/sqllobeditor.html) or some other third-party tool.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, Toad does it-I just had to discover that I could turn off read only mode.

Can it also be done in Mgt Studio?